# Using SQL Server's BULK INSERT with EntityManager's createNativeQuery results in TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So i've been trying to figure this one out.

SQL Server has a way to Bulk Copy using sql which they outline here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017#single-bulk-copy-operations
They even use `executeUpdate()`.

I've been trying to do this with my EntityManager, however I always get the following:
`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

Here's my code:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UpdateService {
    private EntityManager emPreStaging;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "prestagingEntityManagerFactory")
    public void setEmPreStaging(EntityManager emPreStaging) {
        this.emPreStaging = emPreStaging;
    }

    @Async
    public void insertData(String filePath) {
        _log.info("[Update] Inserting data...");
        try {
            emPreStaging.createNativeQuery("BULK INSERT [test_table] FROM '" + filePath + "' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2,FORMATFILE = 'C:\\csv\\location\\test.csv'").executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error("[Update] - Insert Data FAILED - " +e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            emPreStaging.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` but I have also tried jpa's. I've tried wrapping the function instead of at class level to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can yo try to move the Transactional to the method insertData because the method is called async in a different thread.

Comment: yeah i've tried already and nothing

Comment: kinda thinking that `BULK INSERT` just isn't allowed